# Do I need to detach my event handler before I reattach it to the new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a jQuery JS file that attaches an event handler to a link, but the event handler replaces the link with a new link retrieved via an ajax request. It's actually a +1, -1 function, so the link switches back and forth.

It's my understanding that even when the link is clicked twice and returns to its original value, it will become a third unique object, correct? My question is, does it do me any good to detach the event handler each time? Because it doesn't throw an error when I remove the event handler after the link gets replaced, I'm *guessing* that the object and its event handler still exist in JS, they are just no longer in the HTML document, correct? It works fine whether I do or not, but I'm just now 100% sure how exactly the process works.

Here's my .done() function:

```
.done(function(ReturnData){
    PlusOneDiv.replaceWith(ReturnData);
    // Redefine variables and detatch/reattach event
    PlusOneLink.off('click'); // Is this line helpful at all?
    PlusOneDiv = $('#plusonediv');
    PlusOneLink = PlusOneDiv.children('a');
    PlusOneLink.on('click', submit_plus_one);
```

Comment: afaik jQuery does this automatically for you behind the scenes.

Comment: @Jack While playing around with the DOM manipulation methods of jQuery one or two years ago, it became quite apparent that jQuery does do that behind the scenes for you. Though I think after some additional testings, I learned that the native `appendChild` and `insertBefore` methods of the `HTMLElement` class actually already do that. At least as far as I remember...

Comment: @Derija93 That's interesting! Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Ok, then I'll keep it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack Like I said, it was just playing around with the jQuery methods, then with the native methods afterwards. I can test that again with a jsFiddle and post it here.

Comment: @Jack Back with [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Derija93/rFHz5/). I think this proves enough already. Don't know though if this is specific browser behavior. If you want to, you can try it out with different browsers. As far as I understand though, each node JavaScript accesses is an object reference and appending existing references to others then remove them from their previous locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace the element, it is removed from the DOM. If the element is not being referenced by anything else, then it will be eligible for garbage collection and when it is garbage collected, its click handler will also be garbage collected (assuming that nothing else is referencing the click handler).

But if there's, for example, a global variable somewhere in your code like this:

```
var plusOneDiv = $("#plusonediv");
```

and you don't update that variable to refer to the new link that is retrieved via AJAX, then even though replacing the element using `$(...).replace(...)` removes it from the DOM, it won't be garbage collected. But looks like you are updating it, so the original `#plusonediv` element and its listener will eventually get garbage collected and removed from memory.